# Find all values for a if i) no solution,ii) infinite many solutions iii) unique solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

some kind people on this forum helped me reduced a matrix to this.
I understand that if $a =1$ there is no solution. But I never understand how you can find the values of $a$ for infinite solutions vs unique solution.

\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 & \frac{5a+1}{a-1}\\0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{-3}{a-1}\\0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{a+2}{a-1}\end{pmatrix}

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Catherine.... in our previous answer, if $a=0$, there was actually no problem at all, because the term $\frac1a$ got undefined. In the above expression, if $a=1$, the expression again got undefined ("explodes"). That is no other complication than that, only take care of not dividing by zero.

Comment: I think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the other answer, but I'm sure you did some steps to reach this answer **that are not allowed**. This means, you probably multiplied a row with a certain value. But this is only allowed when this value is non zero. So, go look back at your previous question and see where that happens. Then, solve the system for that specific value of $a$ in the step before the multiplication is done. This is how such problems should be handled and one should not look in the end for what values one divides by zero because information is lost.